# Dll signed by unknown company?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I've read something about strong name dll but i'm a little bit confused..
By using strong name assembly i'm sure that code in assembly is original and not hacked by virus or something like that.
But i want to know **which** company has developed the strong name assembly and be sure that that assembly was **really developed by that company**!

Example, i download a strong name dll by unknown site, dll was signed by Microsoft but it is true? Or someone ha s developed that dll and sign it like Microsoft?

Comment: strong naming is not authenticode, please don't confuse the two. Strong Naming is for side by side execution, Authenticode is for verification of origin.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confusing strong naming with certificate signing. From [Eric Lippert's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/03/what-s-the-difference-part-five-certificate-signing-vs-strong-naming.aspx) (which you should read)

> The purpose of a strong name is solely to ensure that when you load an
>   assembly by name, you are loading exactly the assembly you think you
>   are loading.
>
> ...
>
> The purpose of a digital signature from a publisher certificate is to
>   establish a verifiable chain of identity and trust. The chain of trust
>   goes from a hunk of code of unknown or uncertain origin up to a
>   "trusted root" -- an entity which you have configured your operating
>   system to trust.

Answer (score 1):

Strong names are not quite enough to do what you want. You need digital signatures. The blog below has some good information on the differences and why they serve different purposes.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/03/what-s-the-difference-part-five-certificate-signing-vs-strong-naming.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do not download dll files from sites that are not the software developer of the application that you want it for. Dlls are an easy way for malware to be packaged either from the download website or the dll file itself. Dlls (dynamic link libraries) are used so that applications can reuse code instead of re-installing it each time you download something. The dll should come with the program that you downloaded if it is not already pre-installed in windows. Often if a program says that it has a problem with a dll file it is part of a larger problem. You should go to control panel and run a repair on the program.